# How to make an adjacency matrix from three time events in R

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I have data of fire events by type (human induced, natural, accidental), months (Jan, Feb....Dec), location and year (2010....,2017). There are hundreds of unique locations. I want to make an adjacency matrix by assuming that fire events of different locations are related if fire type is same and occurred in the same month of corresponding year. Is there easy way to do it in R. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Kindly share the data using `dput`. After looking at the data, one can help you.

Comment: R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization and general computing. **Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) with your questions. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks.** For statistics questions, use stats.stackexchange.com.